# control goes back to view controller from overlay view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have a view controller for registering a PFuser. I also have a view overlaid on the same view controller that occupies the entire frame but adjusted to be on the right side of the view controller.
This login view appears upon clicking "already registered" button the view controller. I also have the code to fill in the frame with view entirely.

The issue is: whenever I click on username textfield on the view to enter login credentials, it goes back to the view controller asking to register.[image]

//"I am already registered" button action method

```
 - (IBAction)registeredButton:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
       _loginOverlayView.frame = self.view.frame;

      }];
}
```

//login button method

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {

    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_loginUsernameField.text password:_loginPasswordField.text block:^
     (PFUser *  user, NSError *  error) {
        if(!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login user");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
            _usernameField.text=nil;
            _passwordField.text=nil;
            _emailField.text=nil;
            _reEnterPasswordField.text=nil;
            _loginPasswordField.text=nil;
            _loginUsernameField.text=nil;
        }
         else
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Sorry we had problem logging you in!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
             [alert show];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: show the code related to textfield. Did u implement any text field delegate methods ?

Comment: there are no textfield delegate methods implemented